# Using a String in another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label in my `MainViewController` for a swift App that I'm developing. Part of the `MainViewController` is to determine the user's location and display it on the screen. Now, if the user decides to use this location (instead of typing in their own if they are looking for another city) I want to display it as the title of the next ViewController after they press a button. I'm not really sure how to accomplish this. I've tried to declare the `var labelText: String` that is assigned to the string representing the user's location as a global variable, but then I get a compile error that the MainViewController is not initialized, and it will not build.

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to pass the string from the MainViewController to the next ViewController (which I'm going to refer to as NextViewController).

In your NextViewController, declare a property called pageTitle:

```
var pageTitle: String?
```

I am assuming that there is a segue from your MainViewController to NextViewController. In your MainViewController's prepareForSegue, pass the string like so:

```
var viewC: nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as nextViewController
viewC.pageTitle = "title"
```

Then in NextViewController's viewDidLoad, you can make the title of the screen whatever we passed to it from MainViewController:

```
if self.pageTitle != nil {
    self.title = self.pageTitle
}
```